# Remove s-maxage header in Apache Wordpress

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, cache-control

my web page shows response header as follow.

```html
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: max-age=2592000, public, s-maxage=10
content-length: 16671
content-type: image/jpeg
```

I'm trying to remove the s-maxage=10 string. I've been searching for the s-maxage=10 setting in Apache httpd.conf, .htaccess, can't find the source that set this header.
Is there a way to remove it by simple way in .htaccess?
I'm thinking of something like

```html
Header unset Cache-Control "s-maxage=10"
```

Update:
I tried using follow string in .htaccess, but still not working. Can someone shed some light on me?

```html
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Cache-Control "s-maxage=10"
Header edit Cache-Control ^(.*)s-maxage=(\d+)(.*)$ \1\3
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Probably more like https://serverfault.com/a/295996

Comment: Or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167128/prevent-wordpress-from-sending-cache-control-http-header ?